# Display XML content in HTML page

Tags: jquery, html, xml

How to display XML and other type of data in same page ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <country>Columbia</country>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

The above XML should be displayed as it is with formatting. Also , I would like to display HTML tables and other stuff in my page. How to achieve this ?

1. I do get XML in STRING not through file.
2. I do not want to parse it
3. I want to display (that's it)
4. If you say about XSLT ( please give example )
5. I'm thinking to use Jquery plugin ( any examples?)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Simple solution is to embed inside of a `<textarea>` element, which will preserve both the formatting and the angle brackets.  I have also removed the border with `style="border:none;"` which makes the textarea invisible.

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/y9fqf/1/

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful tips and introducing me to jsfiddle.net site.  Will I be able to make textarea collapse-able ? like a section ?

Comment: Awesome answer! I was able to display XML text inside a kendo-grid cell with the help of this answer and the other link here: http://www.telerik.com/forums/multiline-textarea-in-a-grid-databinding. Thanks so much!

Comment: Superb reply. Solved my problem like a charm!!

Comment: Awesome and smart answer. Even worked for java problem. I was trying to create html page based on dynamic data in java.

Answer (score 47):

You can use the old `<xmp>` tag. I don't know about browser support, but it should still work.

```
<HTML>

your code/tables

<xmp>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <country>Columbia</country>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
</xmp>
```

Output:

```
your code/tables
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <country>Columbia</country>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

Comment: "This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it." https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

Answer (score 28):

```
<pre lang="xml" >{{xmlString}}</pre>
```

This worked for me.
Thanks to http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/998872/Display-XML-in-HTML-Div#answer1

Comment: This worked for me, as i was looking for something same.

Comment: worked for me too! I have been displaying xml content in a <pre> tag for quite some time without any trouble. I just recently noticed it was not longer displaying as xml, this tiny fix took care of it

Answer (score 17):

If you treat the content as *text*, not *HTML*, then DOM operations should cause the data to be properly encoded.  Here's how you'd do it in jQuery:

```
$('#container').text(xmlString);
```

Here's how you'd do it with standard DOM methods:

```
document.getElementById('container')
        .appendChild(document.createTextNode(xmlString));
```

If you're placing the XML inside of HTML through server-side scripting, there are bound to be encoding functions to allow you to do that (if you add what your server-side technology is, we can give you specific examples of how you'd do it).

Comment: Thanks...However, will text() preserve formatting of the XMLstring being passed ?

Comment: Where does the XML come from in the first place?  Is there a way you could generate it inside of an iframe, which would take advantage of the built-in browser tools for collapsing/expanding the tags?  Or do you mean you want to collapse/expand the whole textarea?

Comment: I want to collapse/expand the whole of textarea. In general, I want to display multiple snippets of xml code with a page. So, I would like to expand/collapse.

Comment: karthi, the formatting would not be preserved if you put it in a standard `div`.  If, however, you put it in a `pre` element, the whitespace is rendered as it was entered.

Comment: Thanks Jacob - I used `$('#container').text(xmlString);` with `<pre id="container"></pre>` and it was just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

2017 Update I guess. textarea worked fine for me using Spring, Bootstrap and a bunch of other things. Got the SOAP payload stored in a DB, read by Spring and push via Spring-MVC. xmp didn't work at all.

Answer (score -4):

**A simple solution for displaying XML data on an HTML page is that:
go the this [website](https://hintabout.blogspot.com/p/xml-to-html-code-display.html)**

Paste your code and generate the XML code which you can use in pre-tag in HTML[image] to display.