# read xml markup from file and display it on browser

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Probably a very basic question..

But I have a simple table embed with images...So lets say something like this

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">

        <img src="wiki-thumbs/Picture1.png" height="55%" width="80%" class="linksESPN" />

    </td>
    <td align="center">

        <img src="wiki-thumbs/Picture2.png" height="55%" width="80%" class="linksESPN" />

    </td>
  </tr>
```

Now, So Picture1.png has corresponding "xml" data in file called Picture1.xml

So I found a very simple solution here : [Display XML content in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519618/display-xml-content-in-html-page)

But.. how do i read these xml from file. and that too since image name and xml file name are same.. can i do this smartly?

Comment: @scott.korin: adding text area above and below the xml .. saving it as html.. and then linking that page to a cell here?

Answer (score 1):

It would probably be better to do this on the server side, but the question asks about jQuery and AJAX, so, assuming the xml files are within your own domain:

1. For each image, create a `textarea`.  Set an id for each `textarea` so you can correlate each image with the right `textarea`.
2. In jQuery, use a selector to find all of the images on your page with
   the class `linksESPN`.
3. Loop through those images using the [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function.
4. Get the `src` of each image, replace the image's directory
   with the directory of the location of the pdf files and the image's extension with
   `pdf`.
5. Use the [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load the content of the XML into the image's corresponding `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like the link you provided has anything to do with what your asking.  If I understand your question correctly you are trying to parse xml data and insert it into your HTML table.  You can use jQuery for this.

Instead of creating a single xml file for each image, you should just created one xml file that holds all the data for all the images.  That way you only have to make one http request.

Here is an example:

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<images>
    <image id="img1">
        <details>
            Here is a bunch of details for image 1.
        </details>
    </image>
    <image id="img2">
        <details>
            Here is a bunch of details for image 2.
        </details>
    </image>
</images>
```

HTML

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="img1.png" alt="img" />
            <div id="img1" class="details">

            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="img2.png" alt="img" />
            <div id="img2" class="details">

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){

    // Make an ajax call to the server to get the xml file.
    $.ajax({
        // The URL where the xml file exists.
        url: 'data.xml'
    })
    // Jquery's callback that handles a failed request. I'm just logging the message to the console.
    .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus){ console.log( textStatus ); } )
    // Jquery's callback that handels success. Here Im executing the insertData() function.
    .done( insertData( ) );


    function insertData(  ){
        // The .done() method is expecting a funciton as it's parameter so we are returning one.
        // .done() executes that function passing the requested data in. 
        // I named it data.
        return function( data ){

            // You can parse the xml data using jquery selection methods.  I'm using find().
            // This gets all the <image> object from our xml.
            var images = $(data).find('image');

            // For each <image> object do the following.
            images.each(function(){

                // Find the id of the <image> object.
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                // Find the text of the <image> object.
                var text = $(this).find('details').text();

                // I chose to associate the table elements in the html with the xml data via an id attribute.
                // The data in the xml has the same id as the details div in my html.  
                // Here I just select the details div and insert the text that we got from above.
                $( '#'+id ).text( text );
            });
        };
    };
});
```