# how to display an XML file on an HTML page using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

supposedly !! i need to display these thingies

```
<products>

        <product category="Clothes" title= "Rock Paper Scissors Lizard Spock" price="19.99" film="The Big Bang Theory" id="1">
            <description>THROW DOWN
For folks too lazy to break out Urban Spoon when deciding on lunch, we offer a superior alternative to Rock Paper Scissors. And if you wear this shirt while making the decision, you can always remember what beats what because we've provided handy arrows.</description>
            <stock>5</stock>
            <imagesource>images/series/tbbt/products/rpss.jpg</imagesource>
        </product>

        <product category="Merchandise" title= "Periodic Table Shower Curtain" price="29.99" film="The Big Bang Theory" id="2">
            <description>
                CLEANLINESS IS NEXT TO AMERICIUM
Shower curtain features Periodic Table of Elements
71 inches of inspiring, beautiful chemistry
Semi-transparent with colorful blocks
            </description>
            <stock>6</stock>
            <imagesource>images/series/tbbt/products/curtain.jpg</imagesource>
        </product>
</products>
```

on my html page using ajax

Comment: look into xslt to make html from xml

Comment: Do you need to display the `XML` or the "thingies" represented by the XML?

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519618/display-xml-content-in-html-page) wrap all of your xml in a text area tag

```
<textarea style="border:none;">..XML Here..</textarea>
```

This has no border and the textarea won't treat the xml as markup just pure text.

Comment: it didnt work dude :T

Comment: @BassamFoaud It worked for op of that question see the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y9fqf/1/