# display soap response on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, soap, jersey

I'm new to java.
I receive a soap response to my servlet. but when i try to display it in my JSP page, the response is not correctly shown. This is how i forward response attached to the request ,

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("response.jsp");
            req.setAttribute("result", soapResponse);
            dispatcher.forward(req, resp);
```

In `response.jsp`

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1> Response</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><%=request.getAttribute("result")%></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Soap response is here,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:chargeResponse xmlns:ns2="http://p.com/">
         <return>
            <referralDestination>
               <address>919825010001</address>
            </referralDestination>
            <transactionId>REF59369</transactionId>
            <transactionState>CONFIRMED</transactionState>
         </return>
      </ns2:chargeResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But what JSP display is,

```
919825010001 REF59369 CONFIRMED
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519618/display-xml-content-in-html-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `textarea` worked for me.

```
<textarea rows="20" cols="40" style="border:none;">

          <%=request.getAttribute("result")%>   

</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print it using raw mode to escape xml response tags

try:

```
<%!=request.getAttribute("result")%>
```

Or you can use textarea as @jozef-chocholacek comment propose

Comment: <%!=request.getAttribute("result")%> gives errors. But the answer @jozef suggested worked. Thanks for trying.