# How to display the xml tags as a list using css?

Tags: html, css, xml

```html
<team>
  <teamleader info="Team Leader">
    <name>Suresh KC</name>
    <email>kc.suresh@yahoo.com</email>
  </teamleader>
  <member id="ME1A">
    <name>Harry Jones</name>
    <email>Jones25harry@gmail.com</email>
    <salary>2500</salary>
  </member>
  <member id="ME3A">
    <name>John Deo</name>
    <phone>9866123456</phone>
    <salary>2500</salary>
  </member>
</team>
```

i want to display teamleader and member as

1. Suresh KC kc.suresh@yahoo.com
2. Harry Jones Jones25harry@gmail.com 2500
3. John Deo98661234562500

I tried using list-style-type:decimal; property of css but it doesnot work.

Comment: if you are getting this xml from some service, use JS and parse the xml to some object and then insert into the html...

Comment: @Kushal I'd recommend you use an ordered list if you want numbers - <ol></ol> (not ul)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display XML content in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519618/display-xml-content-in-html-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using only CSS, see my example below. 
It is more common to parse the XML using javascript and than displaying it as a list element. You'll be way more flexible that way.

```css
teamleader,
member{
  display: list-item;
  margin-left: 1.3em;
  list-style-type: decimal;   
}
```

```html
<team>
  <teamleader info="Team Leader">
    <name>Suresh KC</name>
    <email>kc.suresh@yahoo.com</email>
  </teamleader>
  <member id="ME1A">
    <name>Harry Jones</name>
    <email>Jones25harry@gmail.com</email>
    <salary>2500</salary>
  </member>
  <member id="ME3A">
    <name>John Deo</name>
    <phone>9866123456</phone>
    <salary>2500</salary>
  </member>
</team>
```