# How to add xml data(containing tags) in extent-report.html

Tags: selenium, dom, extentreports

I'm trying to add xml string into my extent-report. It is instead treating it as an html tag and displaying in the dom instead of UI.

I tried adding chars before and after xml string and then it is printing the chars but not the xml data

```
Reporter.addStepLog("text is <"+"<response><abc value=10></abc></response>"+">"
```

I want the report to show o/p as-> text is `<<response><abc value=10></abc></response>>`
but i am getting-> text is <>

P.S.:If you see the console you will get what i am trying to explain !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try to use following html element :

```
Reporter.addStepLog("text is <textarea rows='20' cols='40' style='border:none;'>"+"<response><abc value=10></abc></response>"+"</textarea>");
```

For information, I found this trick on this site : 
[Display XML content in HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519618/display-xml-content-in-html-page)