# SYMFONY 5 - How can see a XML document in controller?

Tags: php, xml, symfony

I'm working on the creation of a simple XML. It's first time for me and i'm not sure that i'm follow the right way. I need create the XML in separate php file because i will need some time in the future.

I have create, in a /service folder, a file "Converter.php" where i'm trying to create a simple XML:

```
<?php
namespace App\Service;

use DOMDocument;


class ConverterHl7
{
    public function convert(){

        $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        $dom->formatOutput = true;

        $clinical_document = $dom->createElement('ClinicalDocument'); 
        $realm_code =  $dom->createElement('realmCode');

        $realm_code->setAttribute( "CODE:", "IT" );

        $clinical_document->appendChild($realm_code);

        return $dom->saveXML();

    }

}
```

Now i would like see the XML result in my controller.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\ConverterHl7;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class IndexController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/index", name="index")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $toHl7 = new ConverterHl7();

        $res = $toHl7->convert();
        
        return $res;

    }
}
```

But i get a error message

> The controller must return a
> "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response" object but it returned a
> string (" ").

How can i do this ? i'm acting in the best way?

Comment: Create a template for displaying the contents (see [how to display XML content in an HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519618/display-xml-content-in-html-page)) and then [render the template](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two things going on here.  To return an xml file you need to create a Response object, set the xml as content and then tweak the headers to indicate the response has xml.  Something like:

```
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $toHl7 = new ConverterHl7();
        $xml = $toHl7->convert();

        $response = new Response($xml);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="hl7.xml"');

        return $response;
    }
```

The second problem is that you are not generating valid xml.  I copied/pasted your convert code and it was messed up.  But how to generate xml is beyond the scope of this question and I would refer you to the many many examples out there.  I will say this.  Trying to debug generated xml by refreshing your browser gets old real quick.  I would suggest making a console command for testing.  It will be much easier in the long run.

For my testing I simply changed the convert method to:

```
    public function convert()
    {
        return <<<EOT
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClinicalDocument>
  <realmCode code="IT"/>
</ClinicalDocument>
EOT;
    }
```

Just to get the download stuff working.  By the way, with Symfony you will probably want to configure your convertor class as a service and inject it.  But that is yet another little detail outside the scope of this question.